# Windows phone 8 - Sending push notification works from Web Form but not from Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, push-notification

I made a web service that can send push notification depending on [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202967(v=vs.105).aspx). When i call the function from a web form, it works perfectly. However,  when i call the same function from phone i don't receive the notification at all although the response is "Received | Active | Connected". The function is like this :

```
[WebMethod]
    public void SendNotification(string Title, string msg, string url)
    {
        try
        {
            string subscriptionUri = GetNotificationUrl();

           HttpWebRequest sendNotificationRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(subscriptionUri);

            sendNotificationRequest.Method = "POST";

            string toastMessage = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                                  "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" +
                                  "<wp:Toast>" +
                                  "<wp:Text1>" + Title + "</wp:Text1>" +
                                  "<wp:Text2>" + msg + "</wp:Text2>" +
                                  "<wp:Param>" + url + "</wp:Param>" +
                                  "</wp:Toast></wp:Notification>";

            byte[] notificationMessage = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(toastMessage);

            // Set the web request content length.
            sendNotificationRequest.ContentLength = notificationMessage.Length;
            sendNotificationRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
            sendNotificationRequest.Headers.Add("X-WindowsPhone-Target", "toast");
            sendNotificationRequest.Headers.Add("X-NotificationClass", "2");



            using (Stream requestStream = sendNotificationRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                requestStream.Write(notificationMessage, 0, notificationMessage.Length);
            }

            // Send the notification and get the response.

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) sendNotificationRequest.GetResponse();
            string notificationStatus = response.Headers["X-NotificationStatus"];
            string notificationChannelStatus = response.Headers["X-SubscriptionStatus"];
            string deviceConnectionStatus = response.Headers["X-DeviceConnectionStatus"];

            WriteLog(notificationStatus + " | " + notificationChannelStatus + " | " +
                                              deviceConnectionStatus);
        }
        catch
        {


        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to make the application send notifications to itself? I don't think toast notifications are displayed when the application is active. What are you trying to do?

Comment: don't know how i forgot that >.> yes you're right, you can't receive notification as long as the app is running except if you handled the ShellToastNotificationReceived event.  I tested it with a friend and it works fine